# How to run java file which have mysql connection?

Tags: java, jdbc, driver

Can any one help me how to run this code...

If I compile this code it complies successfully, But when I run class file throws

This is the stack trace for that exception :

```
Exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
        at ExportData.main(ExportData.java:13)
```

Here is the code :

```
import java.io.*; 
import java.sql.*;

public class SampleMysql {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String Driver;
        Statement stmt; 
        ResultSet rs; 
        Driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        Connection con = null;

        try {
            Class.forName(Driver);
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/TempAttendance","root", password); 

            if(!con.isClosed()){

                System.out.println("Successfully connected to MySQL DataBase \n");
                stmt = con.createStatement(); 
                String tablename = "Employee_Master";
                String sql;

                rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from Employee_Master");

                while(rs.next()) {
                    System.out.print(rs.getString("Name"));
                }
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }  finally {
            try {
                if(con != null)
                    con.close();
            } catch(SQLException e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please reformat your code, is unreadable as is.

Comment: thats the stack trace you get? Could you post it all

Comment: Add e.printStackTrace(); in your catch block, try to understand the exception, and if you don't, copy-paste the full stack trace in your question.

Comment: Do you have mysql jdbc.jar in lib folder? Posting more stack trace will be helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should download and place your driver jar (mysql jar) file in your class path

[Documentation](http://www.developer.com/java/data/article.php/3417381)

Answer (score 1):

Did you download [Connector/J](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/)

> MySQL Connector/J is the official JDBC driver for MySQL.

Comment: No.Just Now i downloaded. where should i place this?

Comment: You should download this somewhere in your ClassPath. If you are using some sort of IDE, there should be a folder named lib. This is where it should go.

Comment: If this answered your problem, just tick the green very good near the answer to mark it like so.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL driver class (com.mysql.jdbc.Driver) is not available.

Due to that you are getting **`Exception :com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`** error.

Include **[mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/MNOPQR/Downloadmysqlconnectorjava508binjar.htm)** Jar file into **`WEB-INF/lib`** folder, which resolve this issue.